# Unmarshalling to static types using XStream

Tags: java, xstream, jaxb2

I have an XML file of the following format:

```
<TRequest>
    <Item>
        <ItemIdentification>
            <ItemStandardID Qualifier="XX">egosdhgsuh</ItemStandardID>
        </ItemIdentification>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    ....
    </Item>
</TRequest>
```

From the associated WSLD's XSD I have generated Java code using JaxB. This gives me the following hierarchy:

```
public class TRequest extends Request {

    protected List<TRequest.Item> item;

    public static class Item {

        protected TRequest.Item.ItemIdentification itemIdentification;

        public static class ItemIdentification {

            protected TRequest.Item.ItemIdentification.ItemStandardID itemStandardID;

            public static class ItemStandardID {

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to read the `Item`s inside a `TRequest` using `XStreamMarshaller`:

```
    final XStreamMarshaller unmarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    final ImmutableMap<String, ?> of = ImmutableMap.of(
            "Item", TRequest.Item.class,
            "ItemIdentification", TRequest.Item.ItemIdentification.class
    );
    unmarshaller.setAliasesByType(of);
```

But when I try to unmarshall it I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field com.mycompany.TRequest$Item.ItemIdentification
---- Debugging information ----
field               : ItemIdentification
class               : com.mycompany.TRequest$Item
required-type       : com.mycompany.TRequest$Item
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /Item/ItemIdentification
line number         : 2
version             : 4.3.13.RELEASE
-------------------------------
```

In the above call to setAliasesByType, I have tried things such as `Item.ItemIdentification`, `Item$ItemIdentification` etc as the key mapping to `TRequest.Item.ItemIdentification.class`.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in addition to having the correct classes defined you also need to define the relationships between those classes as variables.

ie.

```
public class TRequest extends Request {
    Item Item;
}

public class Item {
    ItemIdentification ItemIdentification;
}


public class ItemIdentification {
    ItemStandardID ItemStandardID;
}

public class ItemStandardID {
    String Qualifier;
}
```

etc.

Comment: Sorry, all that information is defined in the TRequest class, I just didn't put it in the question for the sake of brevity. I can quite happily load an object tree into memory (proof that the generated Java code is correct) but I need to stream it as I have some quite large files.

Comment: I think your exception suggests that the structure doesn't match the the stream expects..  "No such field com.mycompany.TRequest$Item.ItemIdentification"  Do you have a variable called ItemIdentification in your Item class?

Comment: The fields are definitely there - I have updated the question to show a bit more detail in the generated Java

Comment: thanks for that - is it a case sensitivity issue with regards the field names?  ItemIdentification vs itemIdentification